# Does Sonata admin work with self generated entity ids?

Tags: sonata-admin

Does Sonata admin work self generated entity ids? I have the following entity which uses the Uuid library to generate its own id but when I try to create a new Group using Sonata admin it gets confused and thinks I am editing an existing entity and not creating a new one.

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Value\StartEndTime;
use App\Exception\GroupInactiveException;
use Ramsey\Uuid\Uuid;
use Assert\Assertion;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

class Group
{
    /** @var string */
    private $id;

    /** @var string */
    private $title;

    /** @var string */
    private $description;

    /** @var User */
    private $admin;

    /** @var Collection */
    private $members;

    /** @var Collection */
    private $invites;

    /** @var StartEndTime */
    private $startEndTime;

    /** @var StartEndTime */
    private $eventStartEndTime;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
        $this->members = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->invites = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title)
    {
        Assertion::notEmpty($title, 'Title is not specified');
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description)
    {
        Assertion::notEmpty($description, 'Description is not specified');
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStartEndTime()
    {
        return $this->startEndTime;
    }

    public function setStartEndTime(StartEndTime $startEndTime)
    {
        $this->startEndTime = $startEndTime;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEventStartEndTime()
    {
        return $this->eventStartEndTime;
    }

    public function setEventStartEndTime(StartEndTime $startEndTime)
    {
        $this->eventStartEndTime = $startEndTime;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "Sonata admin it gets confused" what's the result of it?

Comment: I can't find the code atm, but i would suspect that sonata by default checks if the id is empty to determine whether the item is new or existing. try to find where that behaviour difference is implemented and how it determines whether the item is new. ideally you can overwrite that in your admin to a different check to decide whether its a new group or an existing.